# If I buy a 1-day Travelcard (Zone 1-9), can I use it to go from London downtown to Gatwick?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, london

I know if I buy it at Gatwick airport I can but If I don't know if I do at Downtown, will it work?
My idea is to buy one at Heathrow and then go to visit London and take my connection to Gatwick.
Am I right?
What do you recommend me?
If I pay by contactless CC, how secure and cheaper is compared to get a one day unlimited transport card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pay by contactless, do not worry about travelcards. The fare you pay will be automatically limited by the **daily fare cap**. The cap used to be the same as the price of the day travelcard that would have covered the same journeys, but is now generally *even less than that*.

(Beware that Heathrow Express and Gatwick Express charge special fares that do not count towards the cap. But nor are travelcards valid for them anyway. Traveling to/from the airport by tube, TfL Rail, or regular Southern/Thameslink trains do count for the cap).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say Heathrow and Gatwick express you mean to the express service right? but I can take the regular tube and TFL service (no express) from/to airports (Heathrow and Gatwick) to/from London and those journeys count on my day pass? Thanks very much for your kind reply

Comment: @LuisOishi: Correct. For extra confusion, beware that at Heathrow Terminals 2-3 the TfL Rail trains to Paddington _leave from the same platform_ as the expensive Heathrow Express. There are employees with bullhorns on the platform yelling angrily at passengers to remember only to board the right train. (The Underground's Piccadilly Line, on the other hand, is an entirely separate station).

Comment: Excellent! I will buy only a 1 day pass so.  Very grateful for your help. A+++

Comment: @LuisOishi: When you write "buy a 1 day pass" it sounds like you're misunderstanding the system. With a contactless card you don't need to buy anything in advance. Just touch the card to the reader on the turnstile your way onto a platform, and again when you leave your destination station. The system will automatically detect when several journeys are made by the same card, and make a single charge for all of them, taking caps into account, somewhen the next day.

Comment: @LuisOishi Also just to clarify. There are no TFL services from Gatwick. Trains from other companies service this station. But you are still able to use contactless, the other train companies and TFL cooperate to collect the fares so you don’t have to worry about multiple tickets

Comment: Hello,I meant for 1 day travelcard but now I learnt that this card will not to take the rails to Gatwick. Henning,as you said the simplest way to go on board is to pay by contactless CC or Oyster C and maybe my question will sound stupid but how can the system know/summary for example 10 or 100 journeys by paying by CC and charge only the max daily fare?Perhaps I underestimate the system and the technology is beyond ''my real world''.My family and I want to be cautious and avoid extra charges especially when comparing your overvalued GBP versus our undervalued CAD.Thanks so much both of you

Comment: @Luis: What happens in practice is that the first time in the day you touch in, the system places a £1 "hold" through the credit card system, which verifies that the card exists and has not been blocked, etc. All the card readers are connected to TfL servers which then collect information about where the card number such-and-and such is used to touch in and out. The next morning the system computes the total price for all the journeys at once and charges it against the £1 hold -- this can be done without the card present, because the initial hold pre-authorized the transaction.

Comment: (It is routinely possible in the credit card systems that the final transaction may be larger than the initial hold, except that the merchant (TfL) is then not protected against transactions being declined for insufficient funds). Your bank or card issuer really does only see a single transaction per day.

Comment: @LuisOishi: If you're an entire family, note that a contactless card can only be used by one person at a time. If you're more people traveling and not all have cards of their own, you'll need to buy Oysters or paper tickets in order to cover everyone. Getting Oyster for child fares appears to be a significant hassle; it may be worth it to buy paper Travelcards for any kids instead.

Comment: Got it! now I feel save and sound to go by myself with all your tips and suggestions. Thanks very much and hope you have a great day

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody actually answered your question as phrased, I thought I'd make this very clear:

**No, a Zone 1-9 Travelcard is NOT valid to Gatwick Airport.**

You can see a map of Travelcard validity on the [London's Rail and Tube Services](http://content.tfl.gov.uk/london-rail-and-tube-services-map.pdf) map.

You can see that while Gatwick Airport is in the Oyster Pay as you Go area (meaning you can use Oyster or contactless bank cards to pay for travel), it does NOT have a zone number listed, meaning it is not valid with ordinary numbered-zone Travelcards.

You can still buy a Travelcard from Gatwick Airport if you wish but it's a so-called "outboundary" Travelcard, which is in effect just a one-day return (Americans would say "round trip") ticket to the boundary of Zone 6, combined with a Travelcard valid within Zones 1-6. There are various available depending on whether you need validity on Gatwick Express trains or not and whether or not you're travelling at peak times, but in any case, it will almost certainly work out more expensive than just using Oyster or Contactless. Henning gave more details on how this works in his answer.

Comment: Ohh.... thanks for clearing out my thoughts. Actually I am new in this forum and first time going to London. Thanks very much

Comment: @LuisOishi no problem - when you get used to the idea of using Oyster or Contactless everywhere it all becomes much easier, but it can take a while to get your head around when you're used to other systems. Hope you enjoy London! :)